# Why do tourist businesses in Mexico give a big discount when paying in cash?

Tags: payment-cards, mexico

I'm staying in Cabo San Lucas and have noticed that businesses here tend to either be cash-only or provide big discounts when paying in cash. For example a whale-watching company mentions that:

> We accept VISA, MC, USD, Mexican Pesos and Euros cash only. We offer a **15% discount** when paying for your entire tour in cash.

Same with a diving company:

> Payment Methods: VISA, Mastercard, PayPal & AMEX **10% Discount for Cash** (USD, MXN, CAD).

Same with a sightseeing company:

> You may pay directly on the day of your trip by MasterCard, VISA, travelers' checks or cash (**10% discount for cash payments**).

Is this because banks charge so much for card transactions in Mexico? Or does this happen because of tax issues? In the US I wouldn't be surprised if a business offered a 1-5% discount for cash, but 10% or 15% would be highly unusual.

Comment: In Sweden you don't get any discount when paying in cash, even though we have the highest taxes in the world 

Comment: I thought paying in cash was as unusual as paying in gold bullion and mackerels by now in Sweden?

Comment: @Mikael: maybe one of the reasons you can sustain the highest taxes in the world, is efficient detection and prosecution of tax fraud?

Comment: in Vietnam and India many businesses will tell you that they'll change 10% more if you pay by card

Comment: @phuclv 10% is a big amount (talking for India). Usually, vendors charge around 2.5% extra if paying by card, which is the fees that card providers charge the vendor.

Comment: @SteveJessop yes, I have friends who grew up without parents as they had commited tax fraud and were in jail. Yet if I have cash on hand for some reason I try spending it in smaller stores and don't ask for a receipt.

Comment: The VAT rate in Mexico is currently 16%.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder. I've heard of a company that charged an extra fee if you wanted a receipt.

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder you know a cash discount is just a credit card surcharge, right? I wouldn't be surprised if the Swedish government just put a ceiling on those surcharges, so there's no need for "discounts" anymore.

Comment: @henning I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are a bunch of legit reasons

- Save Credit Card Service fees (2%-3%)
- No risk of having to chase or eat a bad payment.
- Less paperwork

However, I suspect the main reason is the same as in most other places in the world: To put it delicately: Cash allows for "more creative" accounting practices which may or may not be legal and may or may not result in substantially less tax payments.

Even in the US it's not uncommon for a contractor to give you 10% on a full cash payment.

Comment: Yeah, that was my thought too... I guess the question is then whether or not you want to support tax evasion by paying cash.

Comment: @JonathanReez it's a totally different culture, and maybe you need to look further than just tax evasion for the reason people do it.  Corruption, poor income, cost of living, etc.

Comment: the  IRS doesn't tax foreigners unless they are US citizens, so tax evasion isn't likely!

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That isn't correct. US taxes are due from many non-US citizens who (for example, and not by way of limitation) live and work in the US.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica wat?!? You think the only entity collecting taxes in the world is the IRS?? Rolf

Comment: @user000001 well, what's the reason we care about tax fraud? it means you and I have to pay more than our fair share.  That's not a factor here since I am not a Mexican taxpayer.  I am also not a carpetbagger or imperialist or world police type, so that makes it a big bag of Not My Business.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica your previous comment said that tax evasion was unlikely, not that you don't care about it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica actually when you travel to Mexico for vacation (which was the context of this question), you likely will pay (indirectly) some taxes which go to the Mexican state. So you can still worry about your "fair share".

Comment: @Harper _"The IRS doesn't tax foreigners unless they are US citizens"_ - Huh? Surely somebody foreign to the US (a foreigner) is not a US citizen, and likewise a US citizen is not a foreigner?

Comment: The US also doesn't prosecute muggings that occur in Mexico, but it doesn't necessarily follow that I should accept a 10% discount on a whale-watching tour on the understanding that by doing so I facilitate a mugging. It's up to the questioner whether or not it's a big bag of Not His Business whether he involves himself in local petty crime while on holiday (and I guess whether he considers the tax-avoider or the state to be the mugger in that transaction). But, at least the risk of charge-back or whatever on credit cards gives us plausible grounds to assume it's not *necessarily* criminality.

Comment: @John A surprising number of Mexicans were born in the USA due to parents living in the US illegally then being deported, or legally and their work visa expires. They take the child with them to continue raising the child.

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica, presumably the intended phrase was, "The IRS doen't tax foreigners unless they *are in the United States*" or something similar. We definitely do tax the income of foreigners if it's earned here.

Comment: @JonathanReez: personally I see no problem with paying cash. It's still the choice of the vendor of what to do with the cash (or not) so it's their decision. I don't feel compelled to support local tax enforcement . If the powers at be want less tax evasion and less tax avoidance, they should write better tax laws instead of trying to push the horrible mess we currently have. That's even what the IRS is asking for .

Comment: What risk is there of eating a bad payment, with a credit card? I thought the whole point was that the credit company guarantees the payment.

Comment: Also, the credit card fees (2-3%) depends on the service. If you're using something like Square, I think it was a straight $0.25 or $0.50 per transaction, which can be a lot higher than 2-3% for cheap goods

Comment: @Mars If the cardholder disputes the purchase, it's possible the bank will stop payment.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: when you pay for some service/goods a certain amount X, the profit (so the money that actually stay in the pocket of service/goods provider) is on the order of 8-10% at best. This X includes VAT that the shop must transfer to the Government. After taxes, let's assume the net profit will be ~5%.

The credit card fees are calculated on X (even on VAT!), not on the profit. If credit cards ask fees on the order of 1-3%, it means that they are taking something between 20% to 50% of the net profit.

Comment: Okay, so lets say the dive shop charges me $100/dive, of which $95 is their expense, $3 is taken by the credit card company and $2 is profits. Why would they offer a $10 discount for paying cash rather than a $3 discount?

Comment: Please breakdown the proposed cost structure of said dive shop then to explain the 10% discount.

Comment: Business in Mexico charges 2200 pesos for something.  Unless you're OCD about the exchange rate, you're going to round it to a US$110 dollars in your head.  (Or the business will do that, instead of $98)  Pay with Visa, card fee is three to five dollars, IVA is almost sixteen dollars, business gets 1780 pesos.  Pay ninety dollars cash, business gets the equivalent of 1537 pesos IF he pays the full IVA.  But there's no risk of having to fight it if you claim fraud plus he might prefer dollars to pesos.

Comment: I know nothing about dive shops or their business model. As far as I am concerned, the business model of the shops you mentioned is that the mexican business prefer to give a 10% discount instead of the 1% US business are giving on cash payment. According to your interpretation, you can always barter a larger discount (14.5% instead of 10%) and make an equivalent donation to the Mexican government.
Final note, yes, credit cards usage hamper the creative accountant practices of some businesses, but ... https://www.michaelwest.com.au/how-amex-paid-no-tax-in-nine-years-on-10-billion/